# Chrome - Element Opacity issues caused by 3D space being used in iframe

Tags: css, google-chrome

running into a problem where certain absolutely positioned elements (only 2, with a custom font) are not rendering at their proper opacity. Had a hell of a time tracking it down, but it turns out an element *inside an iframe* being rendered with a rotateY is causing the issue. The opacity problem is actually not even inside the iframe, it's in the main window.

Has anybody else ever run into this issue?

This is a chrome-specific issue since we're targeting chrome and making heavy use of its shared workers.

EDIT: turns out that this is a direct cousin of the flicker , and setting `translate3d(0, 0, 0);` stopped it from happening.